# How to format a time string as 12 or 24 hours using XSL 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, time

I want to write into my XML file a time value in 24:00 format. It will be just the time value.

However, in the XSL file I would like to take this time value (eg: 17:00) and format it as 12 hour format if desired.

How do I do this?

Thank you.

Andrew

Comment: If you can use xsl extensions, you may find a function that will fit your needs: http://exslt.org/date/index.html

Comment: Is the input value literally in just "HH:MM" format, or is it part of a longer date/time string? Perhaps showing a sample of your input XML would help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given an input like:

```
<time>15:35</time>
```

the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="time">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="h" select="substring-before(., ':')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="($h + 11) mod 12 + 1"/>
        <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,':')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(' AM PM', 1 + 3*($h > 11), 3)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

will return:

```
<time>3:35 PM</time>
```

If you have multiple time nodes to transform, you might want to turn this into a named template that can be called multiple times.

Comment: Hi, like it was shortly I was puzzling too and came almost to same result, but your's is better and especially the last substring to get AM or PM is nice trick! +1 from my side.

Comment: Super logic for time formats, especially AM PM identification, plus 1.